# How do I change my home address on Bing Maps?

Tags: bing-maps, location

Bing Maps is listing the wrong location for my home address. It thinks I live 30 minutes away from my actual home.

How do I change my home address in Bing Maps?

Answer (score 1):

- log in to your MS account
- click on **My Places**

  [image]
- click on 3-dots

  [image]
- select **Edit**

  [image]
- enter a valid address

  [image]
- click on **Edit** button

  [image]
- done

  [image]

Comment: I hadn't realized the location under "Edit your home" was an address, as the text just said "home" for me. Changing this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has changed since the previous post. Now you have to

- Go to Saved Places
- Select 'Home', and then 'Remove from Favorites'
- Search for the new Home address
- Hit Save, and then choose 'Home' from the drop-down